# Inline block images going outside div as if floated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When viewing my [website](http://elijayson.tk/), in Firefox, IE, Edge, and Safari the images in the second section of the left column, titled "My Specialties", are going outside the div instead of expanding it. The issue also occurs in Chrome when the window size is smaller than 1200px. I've tried all the solutions other user have provided for similar questions without success. I didn't have this issue initially so it could be something really simple and student. I don't what I changed that made this happen. Inline-flex and clear:both were not successful.

Also, I've had issues with Flexbox acting weird so that might have something to do with it. Flexbox and jQuery (for cross-browser compatibility) are used to keep the right and left columns of uniform dimensions despite the different div/ structure in the left column.

PS I've also managed to add some white space on the right side of the page (visible next to the header) and don't know how to get rid of it. Adding 0 padding and margin to the body doesn't work.

Comment: `occurs in Chrome when the window size is smaller than 1200px` I'm unable to replicate it or i misunderstand what is your issue

Comment: @A. Wolff - Check it out in other browsers and you should see the problem. Not sure why it doesn't happen for you in Chrome. It's not an issue above 1200px. Below that there's only one column and the images in the section titled "My Specialties" bleed into the div below them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The #specialties div isn't properly resizing to hold your inline  elements because you have a height statically set on it (presumably from JS).

Comment: The JS actively changes the height of both columns to stay the same and grow accordingly with the contents so the JS shouldn't set the height statically (and didn't initially). Either way, I checked it and found that my condition setting the column heights to be the same only above 1200px was forcing #specialties to have a static height set but only in Chrome. This would have made sense as it was a latter addition. The issue is still unresolved in other browsers.

Comment: To be honest I'd try and shy away from using JS to assist in your site's layout. Typically depending on JS will only give you more of a headache and that doesn't even account for anyone who may have JS blocked in their browser.

Take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/lWKCDhx.png) screenshot and [this](http://i.imgur.com/ZNrLvPv.png). I get both of these issues in both Chromium and Firefox. (Internet Explorer has its own set of issues.)

Comment: Surprised there's an issue with the Hello image. Thought I'd solved that one. I don't have that issue in Chrome but, thanks to you, just realized I do in Firefox, IE and Edge. In any case, that image is positioned absolute so the height of the columns isn't the issue. Only used JS because the only other option for achieving this layout was using Flexbox and that's not compatible on all browsers.